# How to create raw image in iOS?

Tags: iphone, image, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to create raw image using `UIImagePickerController`. I'm doing like this but getting crash on this line `uiipc.mediaTypes=@[(NSString *)kUTTypeRawImage];` crash report says:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'No available types for source 1'.

Code here

```
UIImagePickerController *uiipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    uiipc.delegate=self;
    uiipc.mediaTypes=[UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:uiipc.sourceType];
    //    uiipc.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *)kUTTypeImage];
    uiipc.mediaTypes=@[(NSString *)kUTTypeRawImage];// Getting crash here
    uiipc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    uiipc.allowsEditing = YES;
    _imgPickViewController=uiipc;
    [self presentViewController:_imgPickViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [I'm not able to create raw image from CGImageRef](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28625759/im-not-able-to-create-raw-image-from-cgimageref)